# Bootstrap 4: Align items inside flexbox item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Flexbox to align columns inside a row.
I need the same height for all columns. So I use the class "align-items-stretch" (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#align-items) to give them all the same height. Now I want to align the content inside the column to the bottom.

Is there a way with Flexbox? Or is it the wrong way?

```html
<div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code you have so far? Please post it.

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: Try removing `row`

Comment: that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to anwser without knowing the contents of the columns. Also, I don't understand how `align-items-stretch` is giving your columns full height as "stretch" is the default. There are several different ways with Flexbox it could be done.

```
<div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Kaby5SlKgM